# AVPlayerItem Pause Live Stream URL?

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, audio-streaming, avplayer

I'm currently using AVPlayerItem to play a live stream from URL.  My code is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://s4.voscast.com:8080/"]];

    [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];

    AVPlayer* player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];
    [player play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                         change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"timedMetadata"])
    {
        AVPlayerItem* playerItem = object;

        for (AVMetadataItem* metadata in playerItem.timedMetadata)
        {
            NSLog(@"\nkey: %@\nkeySpace: %@\ncommonKey: %@\nvalue: %@", [metadata.key description], metadata.keySpace, metadata.commonKey, metadata.stringValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way that this can be paused, and then resume right where it left off at, allowing to fast forward to get back up to live?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[player pause]` and `[player play]` to pause and resume the streaming but you cannot resume from the point you left as a normal track (e.g an mp3 file). You can achieve the same effect as per turn off and on a car radio.

In order to achieve that you should buffering the stream in background during the "pause" and then reproduce it but I guess it a quite complicated. I cannot help you.